# Working with colors in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
Excel_file = "Cookies2.xlsx"
x = pd.read_excel(Excel_file)

sorted_by_Age = x.sort_values(['Age'], ascending=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_by_Age)

def color_chocolate_red(val):
color = 'blue' if val == 'Chocolate'  else 'black'

return 'color: %s' % color

result = df.style.applymap(color_chocolate_red)

result
```

I'm working in a data frame. I want to have any flavor named 'Chocolate' to turn blue and I want to have the other flavors colored as well. I.e. 'Strawberry would be red, Mint would be green...

How do I fix the above code to make that happen?

Comment: please post a small sample reproducible data set

Comment: I put in the whole program now.

Answer (score 2):

```
def colors(val):
    mapping = dict(Chocolate='blue', Strawberry='red', Mint='green')
    return 'color: {}'.format(mapping.get(val, 'black'))

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(color=['Chocolate', 'Strawberry', 'Mint', 'Orange']))

df.style.applymap(colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pandas dataframe and have colors in the column, you have several options to achieve the desired result.

One of them would be to apply your function to all the values in the column. You can use `.apply()` method. The code will be something like

```
df['color'] = df['color'].apply(lambda x: color_chocolate_red(x))
```

this will apply the function to all the values in the column 'color'